# ORACLE TRIGGER INSERT INTO ... (SELECT * ...)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**Trigger with Insert into (select * ...)**

I'm trying it.

```
INSERT INTO T_ USERS SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = :new.ID;
```

*not working...*

this work.

```
INSERT INTO T_USERS(ID) VALUES(:new.ID);
```

**Trigger**

```
create or replace trigger "TRI_USER"
AFTER
insert on "USER"
for each row
begin
INSERT INTO T_USER SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID = :new.ID;
end;​
```

Comment: Structure of tables T_USER and USER is the same?

Comment: "*not working*" is not a valid Oracle error message

Comment: Using `insert` without specifying a column list is considered bad coding style. As is using `select *`

Comment: @MegaTron yes. the same.

Comment: Ok, then see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this work.
>
> `INSERT INTO T_USERS(ID) VALUES(:new.ID);`

So if it fits to you then try this:

```
INSERT INTO T_USER(ID) SELECT ID FROM USER WHERE ID = :new.ID;
```

If you want to select one or more rows from another table, you have to use this syntax:

```
insert into <table>(<col1>,<col2>,...,<coln>)
select <col1>,<col2>,...,<coln>
from ...;
```

Comment: @Edulynch What do you mean by "not working", any errors? See my update

Comment: Seems to be the only way. ty.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could post the actual error you are experiencing?

Also, I suggest that you rethink your approach. Triggers that contain DML introduce all sorts of issues. Keep in mind that Oracle Database may need to restart a trigger, and could therefore execute your DML multiple times for a particular row.

Instead, put all your related DML statements together in a PL/SQL procedure and invoke that.

Comment: I want to know how to do the "insert" with the "select * ..." which worked for me in mysql. (trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Its not about your trigger but because of INSERT statement

here insert statement works as below

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE>(COL1,COL2,COL3) VALUES (VAL1,VAL2,VAL3);  --> If trying to populate value 1 by one.

INSERT INTO <TABLE>(COL1,COL2,COL3) --> If trying to insert mult vales at a time
SELECT VAL1,VAL2,VAL3 FROM <TABLE2>;
```

The number of values should match with number of columsn mentioned.

Hope this helps you to understand