# Using INSERT INTO... SELECT in TRIGGER

Tags: oracle, plsql

The question I am going to ask is already there. But I don't have answer for this.

Please refer the below link.
[ORACLE TRIGGER INSERT INTO ... (SELECT * ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41814292/5744040)

I have around 600 columns in a table. After each insert in this table I need to insert the **new row** in another backup table.

Please tell how to use "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME2 SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME1" query in **trigger**.

**Note: Without specifying columns in insert or select clause**

Structure of both table is same. Specifying all the column name in trigger is difficult and also if new columns added, we need to add in trigger as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORACLE TRIGGER INSERT INTO ... (SELECT \* ...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814292/oracle-trigger-insert-into-select)

Comment: Maybe making a procedure to insert data in table 2 would be more easy?

Comment: @ Tenzin - No, this insert is via webpage. So package won't applicable here.

Comment: @ Krzosik - Around 600 columns there.Do you want me to put all the column names?

Comment: This would be a non-issue if the business logic was in the DB and you just called a procedure to insert the table_1 record. That procedure would then implement the business logic of 'when table_1 record created a backup is created in table_2'. It would be easy and the logic for the business data would be with the business data. the trigger is just a work around for having the business logic spread out and in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SQL> CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER emp_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
insert into emp_backup values (:new.empid, :new.fname, :new.lname);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record successfully inserted into emp_backup table');
END;
```

reference:
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/19839/oracle-using-the-after-insert-and-after-update-triggers/

Comment: Here you are mentioning only 3 columns. I am asking for without mentioning the columns, as I have huge number of columns in a single table. So planned to use select * from.

Comment: You need to write out the columns at least one time.

Answer (score -2):

You should use COMPOUND TRIGGER. This trigger should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_copy_table1
FOR INSERT ON table1
COMPOUND TRIGGER
    v_id number;

BEFORE EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
    v_id := :new.id;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN 
    insert into table2 select * from table1 where id=v_id;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END t_copy_table1;
```

Comment: This would only work for a single INSERT into the main table. If there is an INSERT AS SELECT done on the main table, only the last row will be copied to the backup table. You would need to introduce a PL-SQL table to store the IDs and the you run into memory consideration problems.

Comment: @MarcoPolo OK, but there is not said that insert as select will be done for this table. For single insert is proper way to do this, I think.

Comment: One more condition here is, The id you mentioned in the above trigger may have duplicates. But i need only the last entry inserted newly in the first table.

Comment: @CHANDRUS so use a column which is primary key for this table, I use id only for showing example